# How to group content and add it to ArrayList as one object?

Tags: java

I have a list of Students with the following details say Name, Id, Subject so now I want to use a data structure in which one object stores Name, Id and Subject

**For example**

```
Name: Snow 
Id=1 
Subject=CS and 
 Name: John
Id=2 
Subject =IT
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried creating new class with `Name`, `ID` and `Subject` fields, getters, setters and a constructor?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Answer (score 0):

Create the List of that Student class and add the objects in list . but you have to initialize your class properties either by constructor or setter methods, below example is only to show you how objects can store in List.

```
List <Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student s1= new Student();
studentList.add(s1);
```

Comment: Depending on the design that would probably be `Student s1 = new Student("Snow", 1, "CS");`. Still a fine suggestion to get the OP started.

Comment: @OleV.V. Absolutly True.

Answer (score 0):

Create a object for HashMap class and by using put() method of it pass all the id and subject name as it takes the combination of id and name then convert it to a object of Set class and lastly by using the addAll() method of ArrayList pass set class object to the addAll() method its done, we have not passed the hashmap object because hashmap class does contains allAll() method,below are the codes hope it helps you

```
import java.util.*;
public class GroupA{
public static void main(String...s){
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
HashMap<Integer,String>hs=new HashMap<>();
```

hs.put(100,"aaa");

```
hs.put(101,"bbb");
```

hs.put(102,"ccc");

```
Set sp=hs.entrySet();
al.addAll(sp);
System.out.println(al);
}
}
```

Comment: Now suppose i have more information regarding student say first name,last name, email id etc then which data structure should i use?I was using array of objects. And also i need to send all this information by mail in java.